# Why does log4net wait for the buffer limit to run the layout?

Tags: .net, log4net

I have log4net setup to log to a database table.  The setup seems to be ok (I can get logs to the database.)

However, if I set the logs to buffer `<bufferSize value="30" />`, then logs (correctly) wait for 30 logs before they are persisted to the database.

**However, the layout does not seem to run until the buffer is full.**

If I was logging strings then that would not be a big deal, but I pass in an object to my logger, and then I have a custom `FormatXml` to serialize the object to be logged.  I also have a custom object that has a boolean on it to tell me to create an open or close xml tag.

All of this gets messed up because the log message is called, then the references are updated, then the buffer limit is hit and then the the layout is called (using the updated references).

**Is there anyway to get log4net to call the layout right away, then buffer the database calls?**

Alternatively, I can make sure that my log calls are always "durable" (ie do the serialization before I make the log call).  But I wanted to check to see if I can have lot4net perform how I would like first.)

Answer (score 0):

The DB Appender does not support that and it would require quite some changes to make want you want configurable. You can write your own appender, though. I suggest you download the log4net source code as I starting point. This way you can even have different buffering strategy (not based on the number of log events) if this helps you.